# Need a regular expression for detecting simple math expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm going to validate simple math expressions such these:

```
a = 1 + 2
b = 2.2
a = b + 5.5
a = b - -5.5
a = -1 + 2
a = -2.4
a = 3.5 / 0.2 + 1
a = 3 * -2.1
```

**NOTE: Operator precedence is not important!**

I try following expressions but i got nothing!!!

```
for digits: ^([-]|[.]|[-.]|[0-9])[0-9]*[.]*[0-9]+$
for operators: [-]|[+]|[*]|[/]
for variables: [a-z]+|[A-Z]+
```

I put these expressions in C# string variables and used .net `Regex.Matches(...)` to find matches. But i got nothing!

Comment: If you want a parser, write a parser.

Comment: Is it allways Var = operand operator operand ...

Comment: @Carl! i don't want a parser! I just want to validate some simple expressions described above.

Comment: @rerun: Yes, It's almost true but some times it's just Var = operand

Comment: Could be a useful link http://www.regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx

Comment: @Jalal: Yes, you **do** want a parser. The *exact* intent of a parser is to validate expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a great job for regular expressions.  IF you want to evaluate the true mathematical expression you will not be able to come up with a regex that can handle all cases.  As Carl Norum said it is a similar discussion as to why you can't parse [html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: It's completely different by HTML! it's just a simple assignment expressions...!

Comment: If its not true math expression and you limit your input then sure.

Comment: I need validate some simple assignment expression!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for digits: ((-[0-9]|[0-9])(\.[0-9])|[0-9])
for operators: (-|\+|\*|\/)
for variables: ([a-z]|[A-Z])
```

These looked fine when tested in Regulator.

**EDIT**

First one might be a little 'sloppy', I ran out of lunch time to mess with it :P

Answer (score 0):

Writing good regular expressions for even simple things is harder than it seems. Start with proven expressions and modify as needed:

http://regexlib.com

If you can't find an example, they have a forum dedicated to exactly this kind of question.